# Pass a block and execute inline?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to pass a block of code and break encapsulation to have the code execute inline? Here's my example:

```
  def return_errors(&block)
    errors = []
    block.call if block_given?
    errors
  end
```

Is there any way I can get the code inside block to pick up the scope of the local variable "errors" (without passing it as a variable)? I'm looking to avoid using an instance variable since I don't want the value to persist.

Answer (score 2):

send it as block argument :

```
def return_errors(&block)
    errors = []
    block.call(errors) if block_given?
    errors
end
```

Comment: I knew that, but is that the only way?

Comment: @wise_gremlin No... There is no other way.

Comment: You could try assigning `errors = block.call if block_given?`. That's not exactly an answer to your question, but may help either way

Comment: @PiotrKruczek Yes.. but if you pass it as argument, you are sending the same _array object_ inside the block. So whatever you will change, it is available, once you will be back from the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can "return" it like "yield"

```
def foo(&block)
  result = block.call if block_given?
  p "result = #{result}"
end

foo{
  [1,2,3]
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, but it seemed like a method that returns what you passed to it :)

Comment: @PiotrKruczek Its seemed :D but its nother one way to do it ;)